# Missing artifact for open-saml 3

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, opensaml

Trying to build a small sample project in eclipse (tried both mars and oxygen releases of eclipse). Using Java 1.8. When I add the opensaml dependencies it fails on the opensaml-saml-impl indicating:

```
Missing artifact org.apache.commons:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1
Missing artifact org.apache.commons:commons-lang:jar:2.6
Missing artifact org.apache.jakarta:oro:jar:2.0.8
```

Empty project with the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>testSAML2</groupId>
  <artifactId>test.test.saml</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>abc</name>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <properties>
    <opensaml.version>3.3.0</opensaml.version>
  </properties>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-core</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-saml-api</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-saml-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-messaging-api</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-messaging-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-soap-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have tried to add a repository at the bottom but no change:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>shib-release</id>
        <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Anyone have any ideas why? I have tried to "Update Project...", tried to remove/add as a maven project, tried an empty new project, tried to install oxygen as a new ide and still getting the same issue.

Comment: Did you try adding those missing jar dependencies as well to the pom?

Comment: Yes, tried to manually add the commons-collection with the 3.2.1 release as indicated in the error. No change.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by a series of steps. Ultimately I think the last step was the primary step that resolved the issues (maven build). Here is the series:

- Delete the entire local repository (your .m2/repository)
- Removed all references to older JVM's
- Restarted eclipse
- Reset to java 1.8 interface several times, something in maven thinks its JVM1.5 when I select Maven | 'Update Project...'
- Ran a Maven Build per [The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library - STS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274732) Mike Salleses answer

  - Run as | maven build | goal 'clean install -U' | run

The maven build was a new technique I had not seen. It basically builds the project including maven pulls and you can see the details of what is failing in a log style format.

The maven build finally forced the downloaded of all the jars and compiled. The rest of the test projects all worked with a clean build at this point.