# Java build path problems?

Tags: java, maven

I want to connect to mysql using jdbc in my spring project. I havee added the mysql-connector dependency to the pom.xml project file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.26</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is throwing an error:

```
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.26\mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar'
```

Once I remove this, everything works fine. Same issue with c3p0 dependency.
Please help.

Comment: Where does the message `The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library` coming from? Can you post the full pom and more logging output...to get more context...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library - STS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274732/the-container-maven-dependencies-references-non-existing-library-sts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Go to your project path and run maven install.wait until the installation process is completed successfully.
2.Then Run maven update.
3.Try to clean your project and do maven build.